# SSRS Sorting a data in a column in Tablix SSRS

Tags: sorting, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2016, columnsorting, reporting-services-2016

I Need to Sort the data in column/columns in Tablix(SSRS2016). The Sorting is working when I am opening only that table.rds . When i am executing the whole Project and opening that subreport it gives a error.

"one or more Parameters were not specified for the subreport, 'subreportname', located at: /__rdlname"

I don't understand why I Need a Parameter when I Need just to sort the data in column. 
Can somebody help me ?

I did a right click on column Header -> TextBox properties -> Interactive Sorting
Enable interactive sorting on this text box

As I want to sort with the Groups 
Choose what to sort:
      I have Chosen Groups.

Then Sort by Field which was in drop down list.
in the end

OK.

Comment: Why you are opening sub report? You have used that sub report inside your main report right and you are passing parameters for that sub report from main report.

Comment: The tablix is in Subreport. I am using this subreport inside main Report. Correct,  I am passing all the Parameters from  main Report to subreport.
Is it not correct way to do that ?

Comment: If i understand your question and comment correctly, You have a Report and that report has sub-report. Now in your main Report you are sorting on some column. Let's say you are sorting on Created on Date column and get Sub-report error.
This is basically happening due to some parameter for sub report is missing i.e sub-report is looking for parameter for a particular row but it does not find it.

To Do: Try simply removing sub-report as testing and then sorting see what result it shows.